# A/B testing straight via GA4

Tags: google-analytics-4, ab-testing

After Google Optimize has been shutdown, how can I make a simple A/B test on my site that measures conversion on several Caption variants on button? I don't want use any external tool such VWO, Crazy EGG etc.